# error when trying to change Review Date label in Drupal 7 "Dates without hours granularity must not use any timezone handling."

Tags: drupal-7, datefield

I am trying to change the label on a field "Review Date" -> "Display Date".
But I get this error: "Dates without hours granularity must not use any timezone handling."

Searching that phrase turns up the back end code that generates the error, but not how to fix it.  Unfortunately, I'm not advanced enough to be able to edit/modify the code to allow me to change the label or ignore that warning.

So far I have:
- confirmed that I have the timezone set correctly
- removed the options for "Users may set their own time zone."
- changed the field widget to be a text field

Unfortunately, we cannot create a new field because we already have articles that are using the date field.

In the past, I have successfully edited the name of fields, so this seemed like a simple fix.  Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time zone handling is an option associated to date fields. You will most probably find it at the bottom of the very same form you are using to change the label of your field. I assume that your content type uses a date field to set a date to the node, regardless of the time part of the date field itself (granularity: days). If this is the case, the time zone handling should be set to "No time zone conversion".